# Clarification about the order of variables used in a function

Tags: php

I've been fighting with this PHP-snippet for some hours and I can't figure it out...
How does PHP determines the order when to pass the variables in this snippet:

```
function myfunction ($left, $right) {
    echo $left;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $right;

}

$a = array ('one', 'two', 'three', 'four');

usort($a, 'myfunction');
```

In this case, the variables are passed like this:

```
$left = 'two'   - $right = 'one';
$left = 'four'  - $right = 'two';
$left = 'three' - $right = 'two';
$left = 'four'  - $right = 'three';
```

But how is this sequence determined?!? I've been cracking my head and couldn't find any logic...

Comment: Sorry, but why does this matter? `usort()` is designed to sort your data based on the callback, why does it matter what it does internally? If you really want to know you will have to look at the source code. If you are looking at this because you are thinking of using `usort()` to loop your array (or something) I suggest you need to take a hard look at your program structure...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`usort` uses the [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) algorithm. You'll see that if you change your function to return one of the expected values (-1, 0, 1), the results will be different:

```
function myfunction ($left, $right) {
    echo $left, ', ';
    echo $right, "<br>";
    if ($left == $right) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($left  < $right) ? -1 : 1;

}

$a = array (1, 2, 3, 4);

usort($a, 'myfunction');

/* output:
2, 1
2, 3
4, 2
3, 2
4, 3
*/


/* output when null is returned, as your function does:
2, 1
4, 2
3, 2
4, 3
*/
```

From the article:

> Quicksort first divides a large list into two smaller sub-lists: the
>   low elements and the high elements. Quicksort can then recursively
>   sort the sub-lists.
>
> The steps are:
>
> 1. Pick an element, called a pivot, from the list.
> 2. Reorder the list so that all elements with values less than the pivot come before the pivot, while all elements with values greater
>      than the pivot come after it (equal values can go either way). After
>      this partitioning, the pivot is in its final position. This is called
>      the partition operation.
> 3. Recursively sort the sub-list of lesser elements and the sub-list of greater elements.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, there is no (easy) way to predict the sequence of `usort`?

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials out there that break down the quicksort with examples. Basically, it grabs a value in the middle of the array and uses that as the *pivot point*, comparing the other values to it. Here's a good one: http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Quicksort